# Does a REST JSON response require a wrapper/root element to be valid?

Tags: json, rest

When consuming a REST endpoint, which of the following responses is semantically correct according to the specs of the REST/JSON protocol, and which one is preferred by convention?

Option 1: plain response of ID of an item

```
5
```

Option 2: object response with ID in it.

```
{"itemId":5}
```

Option 3: response wrapper with object in it

```
{"getIdResponse":
    {"itemId":5}
}
```

I know all three options are syntactically correct JSON, but does REST prescribe any wrappers to be used for the response to semantically accepted REST?

Answer (score 1):

> I know all three options are syntactically correct JSON, but does REST prescribe any wrappers to be used for the response to semantically accepted REST?

No.

Using an object value as the root of your representation is a good idea in many cases because it affords extending your schema later to include more structures.  David Orchard's [Extensibility, XML Vocabularies and XML Schema](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/10/27/extend.html) is a good starting point if this is a new idea.

But that certainly isn't required by [REST](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5), which expects that application state is going to be communicated using representations with hypermedia affordances (HTML).